# Extracting Similar Strings Beginning with Same Pattern in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I have thousands of rows that contain different values, but they all contain a form of an ID that I want to extract into a new column.

3 examples include:

1. 02-AKT14H412_MM_Lenan031815
2. 10-AKT14H420-MM_VW_Mire 060315
3. AKT14F774Third-022415-Trends-Digital-Corp

From these 3 cell values, I'd like to extract:

1. AKT14H412
2. AKT14H420
3. AKT14F774

Is there a formula to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: does it always start with `AKT` and have 9 characters?

Comment: Yes it will always have those patterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it always starts with `AKT` then use this formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("AKT",A1),9)
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this easily with a UDF using Microsoft's vbscript regex library:

```
Function regex_substring(strIn As String, strRegex As String) As String

    'Create the regex object
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    'set up regex
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strRegex
    End With

    Dim tmpOut

    'Perform the regex search against the cell value
    Set tmpOut = regex.Execute(strIn)

    'Output the first match (at index 0)
    regex_substring = tmpOut(0).Value

End Function
```

Save that in a new module in your workbook. Save your workbook. And then use it in a cell formula like:

```
=regex_substring(A2, "[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}")
```

That regex pattern says "Find a portion of whatever is in A2 that has Three letters followed by 2 numbers followed by 1 letter followed by 2 numbers." For your sample data, it will return

```
AKT14H41
AKT14H42
AKT14F77
```